# How to parse the following error response from retrofit request?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to parse an error body of a retrofit enqueue. The log shows the response.errorBody as

```
"{"response":["Image height must not exceed image width. Try a different image."]}"
```

Here is my code:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<EditBlogResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<EditBlogResponse> call, Response<EditBlogResponse> response) {
                if(response.body() != null){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onEditResponse: " + response.body());
                    editBlogResponse.setValue(response.body().toString());
                }else{
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponseError: " + response.errorBody().string());
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
                        editBlogResponse.setValue(jsonArray.getString(0));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<EditBlogResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                editBlogResponse.setValue("failure");
            }
        });
```

I receive a system error

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:460)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:101)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:164)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:181)
    at com.example.brandonblog.Repository.Repository$3.onResponse(Repository.java:176)
    at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hello Brandon, welcome to SO. You need to provide a few things here. Version of Retrofit, the class `EditBlogResponse`, and the entire log stacktrace, which line is causing the exception? What is in line `Repository.java:176` ?

Comment: do you have a different response on success and failure?.

Comment: What is the `response code` from postman? If it says `200` or `2xx` then you will able to find the `error message` into `onSuccess()` otherwise there is a little bit of work to do. Please share your `server response` with use so that we can help you.

Comment: Hi, here is the postman error response: `{
    "response": [
        "Enter a body longer than 50 characters."
    ]
}` 400 response. Yes response is different.

The line is `                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
`

Comment: updated with full stack trace, thanks

Comment: Hi. Could you provide the POJO class you created to parse the response? It will be helpful. Please

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that case, your expected response is also inside the `onResponse()` block. you have to lookup into block for the `400` or `4xx` status code like this:

```
  if(response.code() != 200) { 
        Log.d(TAG, "onEditResponseCode: " + response.code());
        Log.d(TAG, "onEditResponse: " + response.body());
        editBlogResponse.setValue(response.body().toString());
  } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEditResponsecode: " + response.code());
      Log.d(TAG, "onEditResponse: " + response.body().response.get(0));
      //because your message is always at the 0th position of the 'response' list
      // You don't need to use any JSONObject or JSONArray etc for these.
  }
```

Try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Ah, we posted at the same time, yes your method works too. Thanks!

Comment: @Brandon You're most welcome. Why will you use extra packages to do this, where my answer solves it into couple of lines, right? So, can you please make my answer as correct. That will be a great appreciation. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, the problem was this line:

```
editBlogResponse.setValue(jsonArray.getString(0));
```

Instead of getString, it should be get():

```
editBlogResponse.setValue(array.get(0).toString());
```

Full working response:

```
public void onResponse(Call<EditBlogResponse> call, Response<EditBlogResponse> response) {
    if(response.body() != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "onEditResponse: " + response.body());
        editBlogResponse.setValue(response.body().toString());
    }else{
        try {
             JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject (response.errorBody().string());
             JSONArray array = jObjError.getJSONArray("response");
             editBlogResponse.setValue(array.get(0).toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```